# How can I add a space to an array using regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, splice

I have a file that outputs data in an incorrect format. I'm trying to use Javascript to correct the formatting of the file. In order for this to work all I need to do is add a space between the numbers and the A.

The problem is that I don't know what these numbers will be.

The example output from the file is as follows:

```
NAME 12345A JAMES
NAME 12345A JAMES
NAME 12345A JAMES
NAME 12345A JAMES
```

desired output:

```
NAME 12345 A JAMES
NAME 12345 A JAMES
NAME 12345 A JAMES
NAME 12345 A JAMES
```

I can't use `indexOf()` with a regular expression, so I've tried to first convert the data into a string, then into an array. I've been able to `match` each occurence of the regular expression, but when I attempt to `splice` in my space it won't work. it doesn't seem to like using `match.index` as the index. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('fileName.txt', (err, data) => { 
    let regEx = /NAME \d\d\d\d\d/g;
    let convertToArray = data.toString().split("   ");
    console.log(convertToArray);

    while ((match = regEx.exec(convertToArray)) != null) {
        console.log(match.index);
    };

    let addSpace = convertToArray.splice(match.index, 0, ' ');
    console.log(addSpace);

});
```

Comment: Why not just `data.replace(/NAME \d+(?![ \d])/g, '$& ')` - https://regex101.com/r/XGA16H/1?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Why the negative look ahead? Does not seem to be useful here

Comment: @MuratKaragöz What  if there is a space already? I guess a space should not be added then. We have too little information about the actual requirements, so the suggestion  is quite generic.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's right. Your answer is correct, so post it as one?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Brilliant, that's solved it thanks. Looks like I need to learn a lot more about regular expressions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `.replace` directly on the data:

```
data.replace(/NAME \d+(?![ \d])/g, '$& ')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XGA16H/1).

**Details**

- `NAME` - a substring
- - a space
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?![ \d])` - not immediately followed with a space or another digit.

The `$&` in the string replacement pattern refers to the whole match value.

To handle any whitespace, replace the literal space with `\s` in the pattern.